# Convert .json data into a MATRIX for a spreadsheet

Tags: json, awk

I have a list of ~200 codes that look like this:

```
EB0016
EB0017
EB0018
EB0019
EB0021
EB0023
EB0024
EB0026
EB0027
```

Through a system at my work, various "parent" codes in the list of 200 are placed in business reports along with a subset of corresponding "child" codes, also from the same list of 200, as shown in the code block below.

To explain the values below, for every report where the code parent code EB0016 is placed, we also see child code EB0148 15.8% of the time, along with child code EB0192 at 13.7% of the time, etc. And whenever we see code EB0017 placed, we also see EB0187 placed 13.6 % of the time, etc. In the example below, EB0016 and EB0017 are parent values, and we can see the child values along with the percentage in decimal format.

In the json file, each parent code is listed only once, so there are 200 parents. For each of the 200 parents, there are children codes listed, and each child has a corresponding decimal frequency showing how often we see that particular child code placed ALONG with the parent code.

The parent and child codes are all from the same list of 200, and thus I now have data where I can create a full matrix.

My question is, how can I convert this json file into a csv file that I can then import into a spreadsheet? Normally I would try to take a stab at some code and then post for additional help, but I'm completely stuck as to how I would even do this after a lot of searching already. Perhaps awk?

```
 {
   "EB0016": {
        "EB0148": 0.1581,
        "EB0192": 0.1372,
        "EB0135": 0.1177,
        "EB0147": 0.0867,
        "EB0110": 0.0822,
        "EB0107": 0.0697
    },
   "EB0017": {
        "EB0187": 0.1364,
        "EB0148": 0.1312,
        "EB0192": 0.093,
        "EB0147": 0.0847
    }
}
```

I would like to take the above json file (I have listed 2 parent codes, but there are actually about 200 codes) and generate a matrix like this:

```
        EB0107  EB0110  EB0135  EB0147  EB0148  EB0187  EB0192
EB0016  0.0697  0.0822  0.1177  0.0867  0.1581  -       0.1372
EB0017  -       -       -       0.0847  0.1312  0.1364  0.093
```

Comment: This is **really** confusing. I'd suggest you to prune unnecessary details

Comment: Why are columns and rows named the way they are named? How is the tabelarized output generated?

Comment: How is that output matrix derived from your sample json? None of the names and numbers seem to match up.

Comment: sample matrix has been edited to match the sample json, apologies for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I *think* I worked out what you want, and this bit of [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) (The de facto standard tool for working with JSON in a shell) should do it:

```
jq -r 'keys as $codes | 
       ((["Code"] + $codes),
        (to_entries | sort_by(.key)[] as $row |
         reduce $codes[] as $c ([$row.key]; . + [$row.value[$c]? // "-"]))) |
       @tsv' input_file.json
```

For your sample input, it prouduces

```
Code    EB0016  EB0017
EB0016  -   -
EB0017  -   -
```

because your parent codes don't appear as child codes of each other, but if they did, you'd see the corresponding numbers instead of dashes.

Change `@tsv` to `@csv` to get CSV output like your question (But not sample desired output) says. (Pleas, please, please be consistent about such things and provide sample input and output that match each other. It makes answering questions so much easier).

Comment: Wow Shawn, thank you! This worked perfectly for me and I happened to already be familiar with jq. I'm really amazed at this solution, thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't understand how that sample would produce that output but here's a shot in the dark using GNU awk and json extension:

```
$ gawk '
@load "json"
BEGIN{
    OFS="\t"
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc"
}
{
    json=json $0
    if(json_fromJSON(json,array)!=0) {
        for(i in array)
            for(j in array[i])
                header[j]
        for(i in header)
            printf "%s%s%s",(++c==1?OFS:""),i,(c==length(header)?ORS:OFS)
        for(i in array) {
            c=0
            printf "%s%s",i,OFS
            for(j in header)
                printf "%s%s",((v=array[i][j])?v:"-"),(++c==length(header)?ORS:OFS)
        }
        json=""
    }
}' file.json
```

Output:

```
        EB0107  EB0110  EB0135  EB0147  EB0148  EB0187  EB0192
EB0016  0.0697  0.0822  0.1177  0.0867  0.1581  -       0.1372
EB0017  -       -       -       0.0847  0.1312  0.1364  0.093
```

Json extension is available [here](http://gawkextlib.sourceforge.net/json/json.html).

Comment: Thank you so much James!!! I'm a newbie and couldn't get this to work for me, but by the look of your output, it would work perfectly. I'm probably missing something obvious with the install. 

awk: syntax error at source line 2
 context is
  >>> @ <<<
awk: bailing out at source line 27

Comment: First you need to download and compile [GNU awk](https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gawk/), [gawkextlib](http://gawkextlib.sourceforge.net/) and [gawk-json](http://gawkextlib.sourceforge.net/json/json.html).